# WIFI connection not working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

We have a wireless network that is set to secure, it does show as unsecure on my laptop, and desktop connect to router but no internet access. other computers on the network require password to connect to router and get internet access. Iphone and Ipads connect using password  and also have internet access, what can I do to fix it.

Laptop = dell e6410

Router = netgear

The laptop work on other wireless networks without any problem

Comment: Breakdown the setup and start again from the bottom up.  Hold that Reset button at the back of the router in for 10-15 seconds, go into the admin panel on the router, choose a different channel, give it a new SSID, set up the wireless security with a different password.  THEN see if it shows up as Unsecure to that laptop.

Answer (score 2):

The firs way is check the Manage Wireless Network. I guess you have 1 SSID in your computer and windows seven can't use current SSID name. You can follow this way: Start> Control Panel> Network and Sharing Center> Manage wireless Network. find your wireless SSID and delete it.

The second way is about your Wireless Modem Configuration. in your Modem Wireless network mode should be Mixed and in Wireless Security System should be on WPA-PSK. I think your Modem was bad configured.