# D-link DIR-636L wireless drops periodically

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Just a few days ago, my router started acting up. We have several laptops and phones all connected fine, then I will suddenly lose internet access. The windows 7 networking icon is showing me connected but no internet access, however, I can't even connect to the router ip address over wifi. If I use a wired ethernet connection, then everything still works. If I power cycle the router, then everything will work for an hour or two before it drops the wifi connection again. When the wifi goes down, all computers can see the network, but none can connect to it. From windows 7, it just times out.

What could be causing this problem, and steps can I take to troubleshoot this kind of problem?

Comment: Another factor: the router was working without issue for a couple months before it started acting up.

Comment: I have the same problem with tplink.

Answer (score 3):

Check your [DIR-636L](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/dir-636l-cloud-gigabit-router-n300) firmware from the link and update to latest. After that there is something called **WISH** on your device. **WISH** is short for *Wireless Intelligent Stream Handling*, a technology developed to enhance your experience, when using a wireless network, by prioritizing the traffic of different applications. Find and configure it with using this link: [How do I configure WISH on my DIR Series router to enhance my wireless network?](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/faq/routers/wireless-routers/dir-series/how-do-i-configure-wish-on-my-dir-series-router-to-enhance-my-wireless-network)

Comment: I wouldn't expect wish to make it so I can't connect to the network at all?

Comment: @Joe I think your problem will be solve from my answer: http://superuser.com/questions/450940/wifi-connection-not-working/450965#450965

Answer (score 0):

Please review this for additional help and information when troubleshooting D-Link routers:
http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=54498.0

Many factors can contribute to wireless stability and connections.

Answer (score -1):

There are more or less reliable firmware versions for DIR-636L. In my experience:

- FW 1.01 - Limited Connectivity on waking up from sleep
- FW 1.02 - Very Stable
- FW 1.03 - Untested
- FW 1.04 - Highly unstable (drops WiFi connection often when downloading)
- FW 1.05 - Highly unstable (drops WiFi connection often when downloading)

Answer (score -1):

i've  DIR-636L and go through this exact problem everyday. I've tried all setting and could not get a fix.
Today what I've found is the issue is related to the "time resetting" or time going backwards. If you check the log the message there is a chance of seeing the message
daemon.err: mDNSResponder: mDNSPlatformRawTime went backwards by 1253278268 ticks; setting correction factor to -921020662 
It make sense when all the clock goes back the ip lease becomes invalid, your ISP suddenly disown you and internet disconnects. but what is not making sense is why is it happening every day. So far I could  not find any documentation related to this issue.

There is Automatic time configuration under Tools --> Time which will allow to set and synchronize.
Another confusing part here is even though my country do not use DST. NTP servers look for dst setting and gives the time accordingly. 
As a Fix: Try setting this clock automatic time configuration with a ntp server  with DST checked.  (I've just made these changes hope this eternal issue gets resolved by this)